# Replace tag `quarkusintegrationtest` with `quarkus-integrationtest`

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I just found that I could not create the tag [quarkus-integrationtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarkus-integrationtest) as there is already a similar existing: [quarkusintegrationtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarkusintegrationtest)

Sadly [quarkusintegrationtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarkusintegrationtest) seems to me malformed and [quarkus-integrationtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarkus-integrationtest) would be the correct tag naming.

Therefore I would like to as to replace the tag [quarkusintegrationtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarkusintegrationtest) with [quarkus-integrationtest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quarkus-integrationtest)

Comment: ***Why?*** Why is the original naming incorrect? Why is your proposed naming better? It looks like the original naming ([tag:quarkusintegrationtest]) matches [the name of the annotation and library](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-integration-test).

Comment: It is much better readable when seperated. Alltogether with small letters `quarkusintegrationtest` you have to parse it yourself before you know what it is about. With the seperator `quarkus-integrationtest`, you immediately recognize that it is about `quarkus`, and you get the sub topic `integrationtests` presented. At least that is how I search for a already existing topic, as it is structured and makes IMHO more sense.
If that is not reason enough, lets drop the discussion.

Answer (score 4):

It's just the way it is. The annotation is named `@QuarkusIntegrationTest` and is a sibling to `@QuarkusTest` and `@TransactionalQuarkusTest`. All part of the quarkus-junit5 library.

So it would be correct to have a tag quarkus-junit5 referring to the library name, but it is less correct to have a tag quarkus-integrationtest. Then it should be `quarkus-quarkusintegrationtest`...

I'm not going to definitively state that it is wrong since the tag has no description yet, so it is not yet set in stone that the tag is specifically about the annotation. It could also refer to the general practice of integration testing applications deployed using Quarkus which technically does not have to be done using the quarkus-junit5 library. It's just a *really* good idea to do so.